# Code autocomplete only in console, not in editor

Tags: r, rstudio

Since yesterday, my RStudio is not autocompleting my code in the editor. This is what I get when I load `ggplot2`, type `gg` and press TAB inside the editor:

[image]

This is what I get when I load `ggplot2`, type `gg` and press TAB inside the console:

[image]

And these are the global options I am using in my RStudio:

[image]

What I've tried so far:

- Restart RStudio
- Restart my computer
- Reinstall RStudio
- Install an RStudio previous version ( 2023.06.0)
- Delete `~/.config/rstudio`

Nothing helped. I found [this topic](https://community.rstudio.com/t/code-autocompletion/142977) from last year in Posit Community, with someone with the same problem I have, but unfortunately there is no solution for it.

The software I am using is

- R 4.3.1
- RStudio 2023.06.1+524
- macOS Ventura 13.4.1

The hardware I am using is

- Macbook Air M1, 2020

What can be done? Does anyone know what could be causing my problem?

Comment: In the first screenhot, have you actually attached the ggplot2 package? All we see there is the script, but not the correponding console output, which should show that the `library(ggplot2)` line has been sent to R.

Comment: Yes, I did attached. But you won't believe: when I created a new script, the autocompletion started to work. [Check this short screen recording](https://imgur.com/a/Rprr0fs).

Comment: Ok, I found my mistake. My original script had ~1500 lines. I don't know why, but I didn't close a parenthesis on line 588 and this was the reason the autocomplete wasn't working.